# Flaskで変数を文字列ではなくHTMLのタグとして読み込ませたい

Tags: python, flask

下記のコードのコードを実行すると、ブラウザ側ではこのように表示されてしまいます。
[image: ブラウザの表示]
下記のコードのdivを文字列ではなく、HTMLとして読み込ませるにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

ご回答頂けますと、幸いです。

```
# 以上略
@app.route('/')
def index():

    div = '<div>test</div>'

return render_template('index.html', div=div)
# 以下略
```

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)に同様の質問がありました。
また、[Flask メモ](https://qiita.com/Prismo/items/7bfd6cd3b4b651b6094f)に参考となるコードがありました。

方法は2つあるそうです。

1. MarkupSafe.Markupを使い変数をsafeにする
2. テンプレート内で `|safe`フィルターを使い変数をsafeにする

### 1. MarkupSafe.Markupを使い変数をsafeにする

```
from flask import Markup
# 略

@app.route('/')
def index():
    div = Markup('<div>test</div>') # divはエスケープ不要なsafeとして扱われる
    return render_template('index.html', div=div)
```

### テンプレート内で |safeフィルターを使い変数をsafeにする

テンプレート内で、div変数を `|safe`フィルターを使いsafeにする。

```
<body>
  {{ div | safe }}
</body>
```